# Thinking of Creating MobileAPP for CiviCRM

Tags: mobile

I am thinking of creating a MobileAPP for CiviCRM using IONIC Framework

Before I start just need to ask. Do we have any MobileAPP that works for CiviCRM? (I know we can view on mobile phone using themes)

Also Need some help for my first Phase- (everything will only be read only)

I am thinking of displaying - Contact, membership and contribution details

What are the details we can display?

I am thinking of releasing the Mobile APP to community

Any suggestion / comment will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/civimobile-a-native-mobile-application-for-civicrm

Answer (score 1):

Per Demerit's comment - there has been a new App developed as described in this [blog](https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/civimobile-a-native-mobile-application-for-civicrm)

Answer (score 0):

Ramesh,

[Webaccess](http://webaccessglobal.com) has developed an extension [CiviMobile](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile) with limited actions like contact search Participant search etc.

HTH
Pradeep

Comment: I think the link is an extension - can we download this from Play store or Itunes?

Comment: Ahhh now i got you, I thought you meant Mobile compatibility CiviCRM. I think we don't have CiviCRM mobile application yet.

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/civimobile-a-native-mobile-application-for-civicrm